# MVC 3 Deployment When MVC3 is Not Installed - Avoiding Bin Deploy for every new site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, shared-hosting

I use a shared hosting provider that doesn't have asp.net mvc3 installed. When deploying my applications, I always end up doing a a bin deploy for the required dll's:

```
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure
System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
```

My question is-- can I place these dll's somewhere in my shared hosting space, and have my deployed apps look for them there? This way I could avoid finding them and ftp'ing them everytime I deploy a new MVC3 App?

Just to add a little more description. My shared provider let's me set up applications within my root directory. So what I was thinking was having the following structure:

**root/bin/(dll's above would be here)**

**root/MyApp** - would need some way of finding the dll's in the bin under the root. This might fall under the category of **binding hints**?

Comment: I've been there. There's no real clean solution apart from staying away from crappy providers which refuse to live in the present. Really, if they don't support Mvc3 or .Net 4 and are stuck with stuff 2+ years old, kiss them goodbye and move on. And if you can afford it, stay away from shared hosting in general. It's way too problematic. Get a dedicated server, or at least a virtual server where you are administrator and can do everything you want.

Comment: matteo- good point-- although overall i've been pretty happy with these folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ILMerge to combine them into a single DLL.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx

On that page they also reference loading DLLs from resources, which I've never actually tried.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx

Other than this, you're going to need the dll for every site if each site is a shared space.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {

      String pathname = "Your path/" + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
      var assemblyData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathname);
      return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
   }

};
```

Comment: I don't mind deploying them once-- but in my shared environment I can run multiple sites - this is done by creating new folders and creating applications from them. I was thinking more on the lines in placing them a folder in my <root> folder and have folders below them access them.

Comment: You can do something similar to the dynamic loading, but instead of looking for a resource, you can load the file dynamically from a different directory.  That'll allow you to deploy dependancies once.